# django 2.1 execute function on add new item from admin panel

Tags: django

i need to execute command every time when admin add new item in tabele Videos. Example admin.py

```
class VideosAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__str__', 'author', 'created_at', 'title_gen', 'deleted')
    list_filter = ['created_at', 'author', 'deleted']
    search_fields = ['Title', 'Description', 'Tags', 'Playlist']
    exclude = ['title_gen', 'Playlist', 'Tags', 'deleted', 'author', 'Category', 'Language']

    class Meta:
        model = Videos


    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return self.model.all_objects.all()

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if getattr(obj, 'author', None) is None:
            obj.author = request.user
        obj.save()

admin.site.register(Videos, VideosAdmin)
```

Every time when admin add new Video item i need to execute function `proccessing(video_id)`, how i can do this ?

Comment: It depends on the time it takes to process the video. You may require to do it asynchronously which would be a different question. But overall, @ruddra is right.

Comment: @AliAsgari yes, maybe i need async because i want to process video

Comment: You can write async tasks, but that task must be initiated from *save_model* method.

Comment: @ruddra i try do this, but i return error, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53527918/django-2-1-celery-not-execute-asyncron-task

Comment: Well, its good that you have posted another question for the problems you have faced. Its actually not in the scope of current question. I hope my answer helped you get the `video_id` from Video Object. If it did, please consider accepting this answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can override in `save_model` method:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if getattr(obj, 'author', None) is None:
        obj.author = request.user
    obj.save()
    if not change:  # Change is False when a New Object is Created
        proccessing(obj.id)  # import proccessing method in the file as well
```